# doPost() is not being called from my jsp

Tags: servlets

when i click on submit button ....servlet is not being called..
it shows the same index.jsp page...
where is the error I am unable to find..Please help me out

//here my jsp
     
                
                    
                        
                            Name
                        
                        
                            
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            Gender
                        
                        
                            Male
                        
                        
                            Female
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            Email
                        
                        
                            
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            Password
                        
                        
                            
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            Contact

```
//here is my web.xml
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet.Register</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Register</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

//here my Register.java

@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
         PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.print("something");

        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
            UserModal user=new UserModal();
            user.setName(request.getParameter("uname"));
            user.setGender(request.getParameter("usex"));
            user.setEmail(request.getParameter("uemail"));
            user.setPassword(request.getParameter("upass"));
            user.setContact(request.getParameter("ucontact"));
            boolean result=new UserService().registerUser(user);
            if(result){
                response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
            }
            else{
                response.sendRedirect("index.jasp?msg=fail");
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Register.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: <form action="Register" method="post">

Comment: what error you are exactly getting, doPost() method must be called , try putting some debug statements to check this whether it is being called or not.

Comment: protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
         PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.print("something"); same error

Comment: when I manually adding Register to url it goes to processRequest

Comment: what do you mean by adding manually , and what is actually you are doing in processRequest method, you code seams correct but i guess there is error in url mappings, also writing anything to output stream directly this is not what you should be doing in any case.

Comment: How can you say that your counter does not go to servlet ? Have you printed any server log there ? May be your boolean result value come false and it may redirected to again index.jsp page .... Try some debug points to that servlet.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer following link with some jsp-servlet example. You can get more idea about servlet doPost() calling.

- [Crunchify.com](http://crunchify.com/servlet-tutorial-getting-starting-with-jsp-servlet-example/)
- [met.guc.edu.eg](http://met.guc.edu.eg/OnlineTutorials/JSP%20-%20Servlets/A%20servlet%20example.aspx)
- [docs.oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a83726/basics4.htm)